# I can't show image url

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, imageview, android-parser

I want to parse a particular xml file using Dom Parser. I am using xml parser for article in my app. How can I use xml parser for image?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://........");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        final NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Article");

        /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */

        nasional.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                    nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Headline");
                    Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                    nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

                    datelist = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("ArticleDate");
                    Element dateElement = (Element) datelist.item(0);
                    datelist = dateElement.getChildNodes();

                    imglist = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("ImageURL");
                    Element imgElement = (Element) imglist.item(0);
                    imglist = imgElement.getChildNodes();

                    View root   = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                    TextView title = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    title.setText(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                    TextView date = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.date);
                    date.setText(((Node) datelist.item(0)).getNodeValue());


                    ImageView image = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                    image(((Node) imglist.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                    list.addView(root);
                }
            }               
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
    }
}).run();
}
```

Comment: Within thread you can not update ui try to use asynctask

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what your question is, but I suspect that your thread is crashing on invocations to the UI elements. You can only modify the UI from the UI thread. There are various ways of doing this, but bear in mind when and how you wish to parse the XML.

If you want to parse it once and retain the results in memory, you should consider using:

- Loaders, where the result is delivered through `onLoaderFinished()`
- Services, where the result is delivered through an Intent in a BroadcastReceiver

If you don't mind the XML being reparsed each time the device is rotated or the activity is recreated, you can consider using:

- An AsyncTask, where the result is delivered through `onPostExecute()`
- A Thread, where the result is delivered through a Handler